# Converting Jquery Ajax to Javascript Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I found a script on the web that I would like to use.  It works as is using jquery 1.11 but I'm learning PHP, CSS and proper HTML syntax and don't need to learn jquery right now.

This is the jquery found in my index.html file:

```
$.ajax({url: 'timezone_detect.php', data: getTimeZoneData(), method: 'POST', dataType: 'JSON'}).done(function(data)
{
$('#timezone').html(data);
$('#timezone1 option[value="' + data + '"]').attr('selected','selected'); */
});
```

This is the php code for timezone_detect.php file:

```
require './php/timezone.php';
if(!isset($_POST['offset']) || !isset($_POST['dst'])) {
 die('Invalid request.');
}
$offset = $_POST['offset'];
$dst = $_POST['dst'];
echo json_encode(Timezone::detect_timezone_id($offset, $dst));
```

This is the JS code for getTimeZoneData():

```
function getTimeZoneData()
{
var today = new Date();
var jan = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
var jul = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
var dst = today.getTimezoneOffset() < Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());
return{offset: -today.getTimezoneOffset() / 60, dst: +dst};
}
```

Now, for the last code this is what I have come up with in JavaScript. But, it does not work correctly.  I get an 'Invalid request.' response.

```
window.onload=function()
{
 ajaxTimeZone('timezone1', 'select_error', 'sql_error', 'timezone_detect.php')
}

function ajaxTimeZone(id, showid, sqlid, query)
{
 var ajax = getXmlHttpRequestObject(sqlid);
 if(typeof ajax == 'object')
 {
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function(getTimeZoneData)
  {
   if(ajax.readyState == 4)
   {
    document.getElementById(showid).innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
   }
  }
  ajax.open("POST", query, true);
  ajax.send(null);
 }
}

function getXmlHttpRequestObject(sqlid)
{
 if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
 { // for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  return(new XMLHttpRequest());
 }
 else if(window.ActiveXObject)
 { // for IE5 and IE6
  return(new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
 }
 else
 { // a browser not equipped to handle XMLHttp
  document.getElementById(sqlid).innerHTML = 'Status: Cound not create XmlHttpRequest Object. Consider upgrading your browser.';
 }
}
```

Can anyone see where I went wrong? I think it has to do with the `getTimeZoneData()` part.

Thank you for any and all help.

**EDIT:** I have tried ajax.send(getTimeZoneData) but firebug reports this long error message: NS_ERROR_XPC_JSOBJECT_HAS_NO_FUNCTION_NAMED: 'JavaScript component does not have a method named: "available"' when calling method: [nsIInputStream::available]

**2nd EDIT:** I have change the code to this:
    function ajaxTimeZone(id, showid, sqlid, query)
    {
     var ajax = getXmlHttpRequestObject(sqlid);
     if(typeof ajax == 'object')
     {
      ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
       if(ajax.readyState == 4)
       {
        alert(ajax.statusText);
        document.getElementById(showid).innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
       }
      }
      ajax.open("POST", query, true);
      ajax.send(getTimeZoneData());
     }
    }

With this code the alert never fires.  When I remove getTimeZoneData() from the ajax.send command then I get an 'Invalid request' error.  How am I supposed to handle the getTimeZoneData() function??

Comment: you do realize that rejecting jquery is multiplying the amount of javascript code you have by about 10 ?

Comment: why `ajax.send(null);` ? why not send `getTimeZoneData()`, since apparently it is what you are supposed to send?

Comment: @njzk2 an ajax request isn't a good reason to use jQuery. That's 90kb of code wasted for want of a 10 line saver? Too much overhead

Comment: Not using jQuery is fine but supporting IE5 and IE6 seems useless.

Comment: Im not much for reinventing the wheel. If i wanted to ditch jQuery i would still get an AJAX wrapper of some sort because they are so plentiful. You could use this: https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/ajax or you could compile your own version of jQuery with only the ajax modules.

Comment: I changed the code to: function ajaxTimeZone(id, showid, sqlid, query)
{
 var ajax = getXmlHttpRequestObject(sqlid);
 if(typeof ajax == 'object')
 {
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
   if(ajax.readyState == 4)
   {
alert(ajax.statusText);
    document.getElementById(showid).innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
   }
  }
  ajax.open("POST", query, true);
  ajax.send(getTimeZoneData());
 }
} and the alert never fires.  If I take out getTimeZoneData() from the ajax.send() statement then I get a 'Invalid request'.  What am I supposed to do with getTimeZoneData() ???